# Simplest way to add an Appendix?

Tags: appendices, texshop

I have looked around before posting and found many different methods to do an appendix. Is there no common way to add an appendix to a {report} format paper ?

The current one I use has this :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix} 
\begin{document}
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Formula}
The contents...
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

However it adds "Appendices" on a seperate page and then says Appendix A followed by Chapter name and then contents ... However the chapter font size is big and doesn't look nice for me.

I want an appendix with the following features :

- Added to TOC
- Can be referred to (using labels I'm assuming ? ) -- Optional
- Doesn't require a full page just for the title APPENDICES
- Appendix (A...Z) followed by small font titles

Is there a simple and convenient way to do this ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Mostly what you describe is the standard layout without any package

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{aaa}
...
\chapter{aaa}
...

\appendix
\chapter{Formula}
The contents...

\chapter{something}
The contents...

\end{document}
```

this doesn't introduce a separate "Appendices" cover page, the Appendix titles are set as chapters. If you want to make that smaller you could do it just for appendices or (more commonly) change it globally for all chapters.

There are infinitely many variations, this redefines the chapter head to use the same setting as `\section` but with `\LARGE` instead of `\Large` so it doesn't force a page break.

Obviously if you do this a lot you could set things up to add it to the definition of `\appendix` so you don't have the redefinition mid-document.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{aaa}
...
\chapter{aaa}
...

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapter{\@startsection {chapter}{0}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}}
\makeatother
\appendix
\chapter{Formula}
The contents...

\chapter{something}
The contents...

\end{document}
```